# Bootstrap doesn't work with WildFly10

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, wildfly-10

http://pastebin.com/f0qgg9fX

Here is my home page. And below it's structure of my App:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkfFO.png)

The problem is in the `<link>` (I think so), because when I run the server I get the page, but without styles, and it looks like only html. I write on my page auxiliary ContextPath: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} and I get there /E-Kantor, it names like my project. I don't know why Bootstrap doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your `resources` directory inside the `WEB-INF` directory. That directory cannot be seen from the page. You'll need to move the directory up one level.